# Google Map API V3 on hidden div (jquery-ui tabs)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-tabs

I know this problem is ancient, but I can't seem to find a clear instruction for it.

The gist of the problem is the Google Map wouldn't load completely (partly shown) when it's loaded on a hidden (display:none) divs, e.g. jQuery tabs, etc.

API V3 wouldn't accept checkResize() any more, the 'left:-1000px' is not an elegant solution.

I've heard delaying constructing the map, and reload the map when click the tabs, but please help me on the exact codes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you say *"left:-1000px' is not an elegant solution"*? It works for me greatly in API v2 and should work also for API v3 (not tested, let me know if it doesn't work).

Redraw, i.e. API v2 `checkResize()` is accomplished this way in API v3:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

Here is an example of my CSS for jquery-ui tabs (inspired by 
http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/):

```css
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide#my_tabs-1 { /* my_tabs-1 contains google map */
    display: block !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    left: -10000px !important;
    top: -10000px !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks tomas. the '-10000px' just seem bit hacky to me, but i will give it a go anyway. thanks!!

Comment: @Rex, just added one zero and it's elegant now! :-)

Comment: @ Tomas haha, yes it works. but i still like to know how to delay constructing the map, or how to reload the map though :)

Comment: @Rex, reloading the map is done through the `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')` call. As for the "delay constructing map" - it's up to you when you construct the map object - it is you who calls the constructor!

Answer (score 1):

In case you can't depend on a Tab Show event you can add the event on Tab Link click event instead of calling `initialize()` on page ready.

```
$('#TabLink').click(function() {
    initialize();
});
```